# Jackson LocalDate Custom Deserializer Formats

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, localdate

I have a spring boot application that uses jackson for serialization/deserialization. I'm writing an integration test for my controller method but I keep getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "1/12/2018": Text '1/12/2018' could not be parsed at index 0; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "1/12/2018": Text '1/12/2018' could not be parsed at index 0
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 165] (through reference chain: com.foo.Foo$FooBuilder["restartDate"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:160)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at com.foo.FooControllerIT.fooTest(FooControllerIT.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "1/12/2018": Text '1/12/2018' could not be parsed at index 0
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 165] (through reference chain: com.foo.Foo$FooBuilder["restartDate"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1548)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DeserializerBase._rethrowDateTimeException(JSR310DeserializerBase.java:81)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:83)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:38)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeSetAndReturn(MethodProperty.java:149)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.deserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3072)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235)
    ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1/12/2018' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:81)
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

Here's my custom deserializer:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase<LocalDate> {
    private final static List<DateTimeFormatter> formats = Arrays.asList(
            BASIC_ISO_DATE, ISO_LOCAL_DATE, ISO_INSTANT
    );
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DEFAULT_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;

    public CustomDeserializer() {
        this(DEFAULT_FORMATTER);
    }

    public CustomDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter dtf) {
        super(LocalDate.class, dtf);
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> withDateFormat(final DateTimeFormatter dtf) {
        return new LocalDateDeserializer(dtf);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(final JsonParser p,
                                 final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String localDate = p.getValueAsString();
        for (DateTimeFormatter format : formats) {
            try {
                return LocalDate.parse(localDate, format);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized date " + date);
    }
}
```

Here's where I register my deserializer:

```
@Configuration
public class ConverterConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.stream().filter(c -> c instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter).findAny().ifPresent(c -> {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) c;

            JavaTimeModule jtm = new JavaTimeModule();
                  jtm.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new CustomDeserializer());


            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().modules(jtm).build();
            converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

            converters.add(converter);
        });
    }
}
```

And finally, here's my IT test:

```
@Test
public void fooTest() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo.FooBuilder().withRestartDate(LocalDate.now()).build();
    String request = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/action-items")
                                                                  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                  .content(request);
    //other stuff
}
```

I've also tried extending `JsonDeserializer` and I get the same error. I'm wiring in the converter into my IT configured in my `ConverterConfig` like so:

```
@Autowired
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter;

ObjectMapper mapper;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mapper = converter.getObjectMapper();
}
```

I've tried breakpointing in my `deserialize` method in my custom class and it isn't being hit. Why isn't jackson using my custom deserializer when dealing with `LocalDate` objects?

Comment: Use ISO8601 format or *nix timestamps when sending date information over the network.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there's nothing I can do about what format the date comes into the system. It's being sent by a legacy system that cannot be changed. I just need to figure out how to make our application read the `M/d/yyyy` format properly